# Flask API is not returning an ouput when a request is sent

Tags: python, flutter, machine-learning, flask, render

i'm trying to deploy a ml model which classifies audio files using flask API and render

here's the code I'm using

```
 from flask import Flask,request,jsonify
import tensorflow as tf
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import librosa
import numpy as np
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = 'UPLOAD_FOLDER'

model = tf.keras.models.load_model('s_model')
d = {0: 'air_conditioner', 1: 'car_horn', 2: 'children_playing', 3: 'dog_bark', 4: 'drilling', 5: 'engine_idling', 6:'gun_shot', 7: 'jackhammer', 8: 'siren', 9: 'street_music'}


def predic(filename):
    
    
    file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
    
    
    
    audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path)
    mfccs_features = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
    mfccs_scaled_features = np.mean(mfccs_features.T,axis=0)
    mfccs_scaled_features=mfccs_scaled_features.reshape(1,-1)
    predicted_label=np.argmax(model.predict(mfccs_scaled_features),axis=1)
    return d[predicted_label[0]]


@app.route('/predict',methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return 'No file provided', 400

    file = request.files['file']
   
    
    if not file.filename.lower().endswith('.wav'):
        return 'Invalid file type, must be .wav', 400
    
    
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
    
    
    prediction = predic(filename)
    return prediction
    
    
   
    

if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However I keep getting no output. I'm hosting the API using render connected to the github repository in which the model and API is stored

[image: Structure of my repository]

I've tried updating the API code and the requirements but I keep getting no output

requirements.txt:

Flask~=2.2.2
gunicorn
numpy
pandas
tensorflow-cpu
librosa
Werkzeug

Here's the code of the flutter app from which the request is being sent

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHome> createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  String? _filePath;
  String? predicted;
  String prediction = '';
  Future<void> uploadAudio(File audioFile) async {
    final url =
        'https://saketh-95ws.onrender.com/predict'; // Change this to your Flask back-end URL
    var request = await http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(url));
    request.files
        .add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('audio', audioFile.path));
    var response = await request.send();
    var responseData = await response.stream.bytesToString();
    setState(() {
      prediction = responseData;
    });
    print(responseData);
  }

  Future<void> pickWavFile() async {
    FilePickerResult? result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.custom,
      allowedExtensions: ['wav'],
    );

    if (result != null) {
      PlatformFile file = result.files.first;
      setState(() {
        _filePath = file.path;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Predictor'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade500,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: pickWavFile,
              child: Text('Select .wav file'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade500),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            _filePath != null
                ? Text('Selected file: $_filePath')
                : Text('No file selected'),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await uploadAudio(File(_filePath ?? ""));
              },
              child: Text('Predict'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade500),
            ),
            prediction != '' ? Text('Prediction : $prediction') : Text('')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

any suggestions?

Comment: when you say not return any output, what response are you getting? you can try some Postman to mimic the request or something like this `import requests

url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict" # change the end point

payload={}
files=[
  ('file',('recording 1.wav',open('/Users/fullpath_of_file/test.wav','rb'),'audio/wav'))
]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)